# I am getting Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Description:

An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service 
this request.Please review the following specific parse error details 
and modify your source file appropriately.

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'CompEngWeb._default'.
    Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="EMC Australia - EMC Testing| Compeng, Melbourne" 
    Line 2:  Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
    Line 3:  CodeFile="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CompEngWeb._default" %>
Source File: D:\CustomerData\webspaces\webspace_00100316\wwwroot\Default.aspx    Line: 1
```

Comment: Did you renamed your file?

Comment: `CompEngWeb._default` this can't be name of your class file. Dot is not allowed

Comment: Try changing `_default` to `_Default`

Comment: is it a website or web applicaiton?

Comment: i would suggest to convert it to **web application** because **website** project has alot of issues like the current one

Comment: @Bharadwaj i have tried Changing _default to _Default But its Not Working

Comment: @BenParker do one thing, if you haven't started coding in that file, delete it and add new or change your approach to web application instead of web site project.

Answer (score 3):

In Web Application `CompEngWeb` is `Namespace` and `_default` is Class Name

If Your `.aspx` Looks like

```
CodeFile="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CompEngWeb._default" %>
```

then Your Page Class should be like

```
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page

{

}
```

If You are Using `WebSite`
Then Your `.aspx` looks like

```
CodeFile="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="default1" %>
```

then Your Page Class should be like

```
public partial class default1 : System.Web.UI.Page

{

}
```

Here Class Name Should be Same as `Inherits` Attributes

Comment: `Inherits` will have `namespace.classname` pattern. in this case `CompEngWeb` is `namespace` and `_default` is the class name

Comment: I am new to asp.net concept, can you please guide me where i get the below code.         
public partial class CompEngWeb_default : System.Web.UI.Page

{

}

Comment: @Bharadwaj `CompEngWeb` is ByDefault Folder Name where Class Resides in C# Logically Grouping of class is namespace

Comment: @BenParker You have to write that code in `.aspx.cs(server side)` page

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar I tried your method in sample web application which through error on displaying the page

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar as OP comment it is web site! not web application. Can't take my vote back unless you edit it

Comment: @Bharadwaj I tried in both web site and web application it works fine for me as error say that page is not able to parse bacause `dot` is present in class name

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar In web application it should be having `namespace` at first and then `class`. if no `namespace` it can't identify the `class`

Comment: @Bharadwaj not necessary. But class name should be same on both sides .aspx and .cs

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar it will show error if no `namespace` added in case of web application. But in web site there is no `namespace` generated so no problem.

Comment: @Bharadwaj you are write i m Editing my answer

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar and your other answer is also correct as OP is using web site ;) add that also